# Prevent Orphaned words in Twig template output

Tags: php, filter, twig

Is there any combination of twig filters/functions that would allow you to replace the last space in a string with a non breaking space? I'd like to prevent orphaned words wrapping to the next line in a responsive layout.

```
Lorum ipsum dolor set amit.
```

would need to become:

```
Lorum ipsum dolor set&nbsp;amit.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this task should not be done in Twig but in your controllers.

But if you absolutely want to do it in Twig you can use `preg_replace` in `twig-extensions`.

https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions#pcre

Maybe this could work :

```
{{ 'Lorum ipsum dolor set amit.'|preg_replace('/.*\K /', '&nbsp;') }}
```